# LeetCode - Check if Given 4 ints can make 24

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, permutation

I am attempting this [LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/24-game/description/), which asks to right a boolean function that returns true if the given array of 4 ints can make 24 through the basic arithmetic operators `+`,`-`,`/`,`*`. The parentheses don't matter because they will be implicitly accounted for if all permutations are correct.

For this question, I use (n P k) to indicate finding all k-size permutations from n elements, since order matters for `-` and `/`.

For the first choice, we have (4 P 2) = 12 and 4 operators, so 12*4 = 48 outcomes. For the second choice, we have 3 elements remaining, or (3 P 2) = 6 and again 4 operators, for 6*4 = 24 outcomes. Lastly, we have 2 elements and 4 operators for a total of 8 outcomes.  In total, we have 48 * 24 * 8 = **9216** total permutations of elements and operators.

My solution works for 69/70 of LeetCode's test cases (the list 3,3,8,8 incorrectly returns false). However, anytime I try to adjust the code to get this last test case to work, a new set of test cases fail. The code seems correct, but obviously it isn't, and after hours and hours I'm still stumped.

First, a helper method that swaps two elements in an array.

```
// swap indices x and y of array A
static void swap(double[] A, int x, int y) {
    double temp = A[x];
    A[x] = A[y];
    A[y] = temp;
}
```

The core idea is to keep the remaining values in `A[0..right]` (note the inclusive upper bound). Indicies `i` and `j` denote the 2 elements chosen for the operation. Place this new result in `i`.

Now `A[j]`, used up in that computation, needs to be "deleted". This is done by swapping `j` with `right`. In the recursive call, decrement `right` because you combined 2 values with some operator and are now left with 1 fewer elements. So now `j` resides in the right partition of the array that will no longer be used in future computations.

```
/**
 * Iterate through all 9216 permutations of elements and operators until a permutation
 * that can make 24 has been found.
 * 
 * @param  A     Array of doubles
 * @param  right Rightmost index of current subarray A[0..right],
                 which stores the remaining elements
 * @return       True if the original given array can produce 24
 */
static boolean permute(double[] A, int right) {
    // base case, array of size 1
    if (right == 0) { return A[0] == 24; }

    // choose 2 distinct elements and apply all 4 operators
    for (int i = 0; i <= right; i++) {
        double temp = A[i];  // used for restoring value later

        for (int j = 0; j <= right; j++) {
            if (i==j) continue;

            for (int op = 0; op < 4; op++) {
                switch(op) {
                    case 0: A[i] += A[j]; break;
                    case 1: A[i] *= A[j]; break;
                    case 2: { if(A[j] <= 0) return false;
                                A[i] /= A[j]; break; }
                    case 3: A[i] -= A[j]; break;
                }

                swap(A,j,right);
                if(permute(A,right-1)) return true;

                // restore values
                swap(A,j,right);
                A[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

While debugging, I added print statements and for every single case, whether the actual boolean was right or wrong, exactly 9216 arrays were printed, so I know the number of iterations is correct. I suspect the error occurs when I restore the values after the recursive call in the inner `for` loop.

Additional method that allows compatibility with `int[]`

```
static boolean make24(int[] A) {
    return permute(IntStream.of(A).mapToDouble(num -> num).toArray(), A.length-1);
}
```

Finally, the driver method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] {8,8,3,3};  
    System.out.println(make24(a));  // incorrectly returns false
}
```

Additional test cases which may be useful:

```
1,3,4,6 --> true
3,3,8,8 --> true
1,2,1,2 --> false
3,4,6,7 --> false
1,5,9,1 --> false
```

I've tried commenting and explaining as best I can without being excessive. I'm asking for a lot here so I don't expect many responses but thank you for reading this post!

**Edit:** From this [solution I found](https://github.com/fishercoder1534/Leetcode/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fishercoder/solutions/_679.java), it appears that the arbitrary precision arithmetic might be causing some errors.  For example, instead of `return A[0] == 24;`, do `return Math.abs(A[0]-24) < 1e-8;`. Making these changes fixes the program, so the actual algorithm logic was ok :)

Comment: One possible error I see is Case 2.  You are blindly doing A[i] = A[i]/A[j]. What if the A[j]=0? You will get exception. Try fixing this by making sure that A[j]>0.

Comment: Great catch. The program is still failing the case (3,3,8,8), but it is still correct to include it.